# Ошибка 18456 при входе MS SQL 2019

Tags: sql, sql-server

Данные введены верно, смешанное подключение поставил, пользователю поставил галку sysadmin и членство public.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нажмите "Показать подробности", там должна быть дополнительная информация.